# Google returning 400 Parse Error

Tags: python, parse-error, google-mirror-api

I've recently been getting a 400 bad request parse error when making a request to my timeline_url.

Im posting to this url  `timeline_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/timeline'`

**EDIT**
Here is the code:

```
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               'Authorization' : 'Bearer %s' % access_token}
    body = {"text" : "Waddup doe!"}
    """ ***********THIS IS RETURNING ERROR 400 PARSE ERROR***********"""
    send_request(timeline_url, headers, 'POST',body)
```

The send_request method is using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html)

```
req = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)
```

I'm just trying to insert plain text to my timeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
body_bytes = sys.getsizeof(body)
headers['Content-Length'] = body_bytes
```

This is inserting an incorrect value into your request headers. `sys.getsizeof` describes how large the data structure is -- including pointers, counters, etc. It does *NOT* describe how many bytes the string representation takes on the HTTP stream.

Just delete these lines; `requests` will fill in `Content-Length` automatically.

---

You don't describe how you json-encode the payload. Perhaps you need to do this:

```
req = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers)
```

See: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Comment: I was doing that at first and it was still returning 400 parse error. I thought maybe the request was incorrect because it was missing content-length. You are right, requests does fill that automatically.

Comment: Maybe you've failed to json-encode the body? See my latest edit.

Comment: I knew it worked before I had forgotten how it was done. json.dumps() was missing. Thank you, great observation.